# Law of Iterated Expectations: Bivariate Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

The law of iterated expectations states the following:
$$\text{E}\left[ \text{E} \left[ \mathbb{X} | \mathbb{Y} \right] \right] = \text{E}\left[ \mathbb{X} \right]$$

Given a bivariate Gaussian (normal) joint pdf with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ and correlation coefficient $\rho$ 
$$\text{E}[\mathbb{X}|\mathbb{Y} = y] = \mu_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(y - \mu_2)$$
Does this concur with:
$$\text{E}\left[ \text{E} \left[ \mathbb{X} | \mathbb{Y} \right] \right] = \text{E}\left[ \mathbb{X} \right]$$

**Attempted Solution**:

Since $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, and $\rho$ are all numbers and $\text{E}[\bullet]$ is a linear operator, I did the following:
$$\text{E}\left[ \text{E} \left[ \mathbb{X} | \mathbb{Y} \right] \right] = \mu_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(\text{E}[y] - \mu_2)$$
and
$$\text{E}[\mathbb{Y}] = \mu_2$$
so the above reduces to:

$$\text{E}\left[ \text{E} \left[ \mathbb{X} | \mathbb{Y} \right] \right] = \mu_1 $$

**Question**:

Am I allowed to assume that $\text{E}[\mathbb{Y}] = \mu_2$ by definition of a bivariate normal? Or do I have to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X|Y=y)=g(y)$ is a number but $E(X|Y)=g(Y)$ is a random variable.

by definition you get:
$$g(y)=E(X|Y=y)=\mu_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(y - \mu_2)$$

so

$$g(Y)=E(X|Y)=\mu_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(Y - \mu_2)$$

Comment: That makes sense, I realized my notation got mixed up. Is it then true $\text{E}[\mathbb{Y}] = \mu_2$? Or does that need to be proven?

Comment: Yes. $E(Y)=\mu_2$ but $E(y)=y$ since $y$ is a number.

Answer (score 1):

The question was changed.  As it stands now, you are given that $(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y})$ has mean $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ so of course you can assume $E[\mathbb{Y}] = \mu_2$.

**For the original question:**

The notation $E[\mathbb{X}\mid\mathbb{Y}=y]$ denotes a function from the range of $\mathbb{Y}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with variable $y$.  Therefore, $E[y] = y,$ as this variable is not directly endowed with a distribution (in my experience, this has been the whole point of that notation)

To compare it to the law of iterated expectation, you need to compose this function with $\mathbb{Y}$ to get $$E[E[\mathbb{X}\mid\mathbb{Y}=y]\circ \mathbb{Y}] = E[\mathbb{X}]$$

Comment: Yes, I believe my original notation was slightly incorrect, since the second expectation is only a function of $y$ I can apply the definition of expectations there.